# Decorating Jasmine's API when using Protractor

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, protractor

is there a way (when using Protractor + Jasmine) to decorate [Jasmine's global interface](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/boot.html#section-The_Global_Interface)? I would like to have the identifier from our SRS in the reporter/output.

We already do this for our unit tests run with Karma:

```
var jit = env.it;
env.it = function(srs_id, desc, func) {
    // Do something with the srs_id
    return jit(desc, func);
};

// Same for "fit" and "xit"
```

When I do this in `onPrepare` the tests will run, but focused testing won't work :( Instead of only run the tests called with `fit` all tests will run.

The different behaviour can be achieved by using 3 arguments for a test (`it`/`fit`) with/ or without decorating the method. E.g.

```
it('additional parameter', 'should test something', () => {
  expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});
```

- **Karma** will execute everything as expected. When the `it` with 3 arguments is executed an error is thrown (`queueableFn.fn.call is not a function`). If a `fdescribe`/`fit` is used only those tests are run.
- **Protractor** will also throw an error (`Constraints encountered a declaration exception`) when it encounteres the method with 3 parameters. It will also print out the correct spec description, e.g. `'should test something'`. `fdescribe`/`fit` is ignored, all specs executed.

*Versions:* node@5.3.0, karma@0.13.15, protractor@3.0.0

My guess would be Protractor itself decorates the API provided by Jasmine. Is decorating Jasmine inside the `onPrepare` the correct place? And if so is there a way to decorate the Jasmine methods?